# displaying data from MySQL in PHP according to a condition

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display data from MySQL database using PHP according to availability.
Here is the snippet:

```
include_once ('functions.php');
    $con = new DB_con();
    $res=$con->selectemployer();
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        ?>
<?php

if ($row['stat'] == 'Available') {
    echo '<td data-value="' . $row['employerid'] . '"><span class="label label-success status-active" title="Available">' . $row['stat'] . '</span></td>';
} else {
    echo '<td data-value="' . $row['employerid'] . '"><span class="label label-warning status-suspended" title="Unavailable" style="background-color:red;">' . $row['stat'] . '</span></td>';
}
?>
```

Here is functions.php :

```
class DB_con
{
public function selectemployer()
 {
   $res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employer");
  return $res;
 }
}
```

My issue is that whenever I select Unavailable,it displays correctly(i.e only rows with Unavailable status).But on selecting 'Available' option,it shows both unavailable and available rows.
Where am I wrong here ?

EDIT:Resolved the issue , the problem was because of a JS script which was performing the sorting.

Comment: This code is insufficient to understand your problem.

Comment: What possible values does `$row['stat']` can have ?

Comment: Your code is not consistent with the behavior you are describing.  Are you _sure_ that this code is what you have running in production?

Comment: @syedsuleman : Available and Unavailable

Comment: You need a where clause in your query

Comment: Well anything will work if you assign it using =.Sorry it doesnt help @syedsuleman

Comment: @shri_wahal It was just for test purpose... Try to print values of `$row['stat']` and check what values you get.

Comment: Thanks @saty, tim ,@luthando .Will definitely take care for the questions from now on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query does not have a where clause, fix it this way

```
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employer WHERE status = '".$_Post['stat']."'");
```

I am assuming the column that contains Available/Unavailable is `status` and the status field name that you post in your html is `$_Post['stat']`